# remove marker from google maps by the id using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map with several markers where the location comes from firebase up to that point, all right. The problem is when the possiblity of the marked update it to create a new marker rather than deletes the old one.

I have already researched here on the site but none answered the question.
Either delete all or only one at a time.

That is why I am opening this new question. Thank you all right away.

```
<?php

mysql_select_db($database_vpt2, $vpt2);
$query_onlines = "SELECT * FROM motoristas WHERE `online` = 1";
$onlines = mysql_query($query_onlines, $vpt2) or die(mysql_error());
$row_onlines = mysql_fetch_assoc($onlines);
$totalRows_onlines = mysql_num_rows($onlines);
?>   

<script type="text/javascript">

var markers = [];
function initMap() {

var myLatLng = {lat: -5.079166, lng: -42.812019};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: myLatLng
        });

<?php do { ?>  

var adaRef = firebase.database().ref("local/<?php echo $row_onlines['id_motorista']; ?>");

adaRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

    var rodar = parseInt(snapshot.val() .giro);
    var lat1 = snapshot.val() .latitude; 
    var lng1 = snapshot.val() .longitude; 



    var myLatLng = {lat: lat1, lng: lng1};

      var image = '../icon/marker.png';         
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
          id: <?php echo $row_onlines['id_motorista']; ?>,
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'OK',
          icon: image,
        });
        markers.push(marker);

});



<?php } while ($row_onlines = mysql_fetch_assoc($onlines)); ?>


}

</script>
```

Comment: The code above already does this add the marker all right the problem is not this one. the question is when I get a new location coming from the firebase he create a new bookmark but does not delete the old bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the marker by keeping the reference of markers in an array. Then update it something like below.

```
var myNewLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-2.363882,131.044922);
marker.setPosition(myNewLatlng);
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker